# How to create Folder and files on Server using .net windowsForm

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I  am  working on windows form, i have  one task to create directory and files on My client server using windows Form. So  how can i create Directory and Files on Client

Server using my windows/Desktop Application.

Thanks

I  have no  idea..  Means  how can i authenticate my desktop to My Live Server

I was Just trying that code but its not working

```
string path= "\\ipaddress\\Templates\\";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@path);
```

If  i  try  this  one

```
string path = "\\123.100.000.000\KapilSearch\";
```

I am  having following error

```
[Error  1   Unrecognized escape sequence]
[Error  2   Newline in constant]
```

Comment: That code should work taken that your application have the right privileges to write to that location on the network. When you say not working what exactly is happening? Do you get any exception?

Comment: i am also worrying, that i am not getting any exception ..if it is some authentication problem then it should show some Access denied error..but  nothing happen.

Comment: a number of issues... 1. if that is really your code, the path is wrong since the first backslash is escaped, you'd need something like: `path = @"\\ipaddress\templates\"`. 2. Please clarify the scenario - winForms app running on DesktopA and you want to create a folder on ServerB but without running any code on ServerB?

Comment: yes   u  r  right i need to create directory on my serverB winthout any code of ServerB...for regarding path please check edit

Comment: You have two problems here, escaping, and the fact that you're trying to create a directory. A UNC is in the format `\\ServerName\ShareName` - and you should consider this a root directory. NB, the share must be set up on the server first by an administrator. You can then do `Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\ServerName\ShareName\SomeDirectory");` to create a folder inside that share. Regarding escaping, I have improved @chris' answer to give you both your options.

Comment: i  have  tried  this  one also ...But  again  getting  error   network path not found

Answer (score 0):

Your path is escaped incorrectly. You have two options.

```
string path= @"\\ServerName\ShareName\targetnewfolder";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

or this:

```
string path = "\\\\ServerName\\ShareName\\targetnewfolder";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Note the @ in front of the open string - and that the slashes are equal to the number you would use in windows explorer - no escapes required when using the @ modifier. 
Note also, no @ sign in the CreateDirectory argument.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, your answer is the most correct one here and I just added a bit more detail to it.

Comment: i  have  used  this string path= @"\\ipaddress\D:\Templates\";   but  showing error "The given path's format is not supported."

Comment: sigh... ok, when I said "as you would in windows explorer" perhaps I confused matters. You need to create a windows share on your server. D: is a drive mapped on the server not a share

Comment: @KapsHasija Go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing) and read the section entitled `Uniform Naming Convention`, then come back here.

Answer (score -1):

If you are you asking how to create a directory, then this is as simple as:
[Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: i am using Windows application..  like if user doing some logical part using windows app then i have to create folder on my server system location not in user location.

Comment: Most of this should be a comment.